# C# Regex replace with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem, I want to replace every "[[:de:<text>]]" with "{{de|<text>}}" in some text. I tried with

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, "[[:de:(.*)]]", "{{de|(.*)}}");
```

but it doesnt copy the <text>.
I have no other idea how to replace this correctly.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: Use String.Replace. If you don't want it to treat `"[[:de:(.*)]]"` as a regex, don't ask it to.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lazy dot pattern and  backreferences and escape the `[`  symbols:

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\[\[:de:(.*?)]]", "{{de|$1}}");
```

If the text between `de:`  and `]]` can contain line breaks, use `RegexOptions.Singleline` modifier.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5c%5b%3ade%3a%28.*%3f%29%5d%5d&i=%5b%5b%3ade%3atext1%5d%5d+and+%5b%5b%3ade%3atext2%0d%0aand+more%5d%5d&r=%7b%7bde%7c%241%7d%7d&o=s).

[image]

Comment: Also, see [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details on .NET replacement backreferences.

Comment: You miss the `@` before the pattern.

Comment: @aloisdg: Sure, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you encapsulate everything inside groups, you can benefit of a MatchEvaluator. [Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L5FJAG).

```
public static void Main()
{
    var input = "[[:de:Hello World]]";
    var pattern = @"(\[\[:de:)(.+)(\]\])";
    var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => "{{de|" +  m.Groups[2].Value + "}}");
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

output

```
{{de|Hello World}}
```

Comment: Match evaluator can be saved for more complex scenarios, replacement backreferences are enough here. The greedy dot will also mess the output that contains several matches on a single line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need regex ? I think you can only use string replace method;

```
output = input.Replace("[[:de:(.*)]]", "{{de|(.*)}}");
```

Comment: `(.*)` is a regex. OP wants to replace `[[:de:Hello World]]` to `{{de|Hello World}}`.